# add local variable and pointer variable

Tags: c, pointers, variables

I'm a beginner in C language.
I'm practicing several codes on my own, while doing I came across this algo.
Below is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   
   int a = 1;
   printf("value of a = %d\n", a);
   printf("address of a = %u\n", &a);
   
   int *p;
   printf("value of p = %d\n", p);
   
   p = 2;
   printf("value of p = %d\n", p);
   
   a = a+p;
   printf("value of addition =%d\n", a);
  
    return 0;
}



**OUTPUT** 
value of a = 1
address of a = 947268620
value of p = 947268880
value of p = 2
value of addition =6
```

Why I'm getting 6 instead of 3,
is there anything I'm missing on result

Comment: What isthe algo supposed to do?

Comment: Please use appropriate format strings to fix undefined behaviour and try again. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you're not setting the value of the address p is pointing to to 2, you're assigning/pointing the variable int *p to the value 2 in memory, which is not memory you should be accessing. Instead, you need to point p to memory you have access to (a variable or dynamically allocated memory) and dereference the pointer using `*p = 2` which accesses the value that p is pointing to. Your code should instead look like this

```
int a = 1;
printf("value of a = %d\n", a);
printf("address of a = %u\n", &a); 
int _p = 0;
int *p = &_p;
printf("value of p = %d\n", *p);
*p = 2;
printf("value of p = %d\n", *p);
a = a+*p;
printf("value of addition =%d\n", a);
```

Comment: "you're not setting the value of the address p is pointing to to 2" I find your assumption that OP is trying that implausible. Only when doing as you recommend `*p = 2` the code would get really ilelgal, without allocationn beforehand. Even in the code you show that is not done and it IS accessing in illegal memory. OP in contrast is experimenting with pointer arithmetic and is NOT deregencing 2. Without the commenting privilege you cannot clarify OPs intentions. Your answer is daring, does not explain what OP observes and proposes unwise code.

Comment: What OP is wondering about is either caused or hidden by the UB they have in their code. A good answer would need that clarified first.

Comment: And of course your proposed code has the same cause of undefined behaviour as the code by OP.

Comment: great catch I didn't realize that @Yunnosch thank you for pointing that out! I updated it to have p point to an int variable that was assigned before _p, the memory p points to could also be created dynamically but it's easier to show by doing this instead

Comment: Thanks, but that does not really help. You are still making implausbile (to me) assummptions on what OP is wondering about. Also now you are unwisely using an identfier starting with a `_`.

Comment: also he is dereferencing 2 lol, he wants the value to be 3 which is got by adding 1 and 2, not sure where you got pointer arithmetic from

Comment: I think complaining about the underscore is nitpicking atp :p

Comment: As far as I can tell they are not dereferencing 2. Please quote the code you are referring to with that.

Comment: "Why I'm getting 6 instead of 3, is there anything I'm missing on result" He wants the value to be 3, so clearly he wants to dereference so he can add 1 and 2 to get 3

Comment: That is also what I mean by "pointer artithmetic". It is however not where they are dereferencing 2. It also does not seem to be where they are trying to. They are expecting 1+2 to be three. They do not dereference, they do not try to dereference (it would contradict the expectation of 3).

Comment: I think he didn't dereference p because he doesn't understand what the dereference operator does, as to the pointer arithmetic comment I've only seen that discussed when working with arrays/sequential memory so that's why it was confusing

Comment: Admittedly, I am guessing as much as you. The difference is that you guess and then assume and make an answer on that assumption. I recommend to wait for clarification before answering. I asked for clarification (to help you as much as my curiosity. If you want to ask a question for clarification I offer to add it as a comment.)

Comment: glad we came to a solid conclusion, I think waiting is best

Comment: Good answer. Should have more upvotes

Comment: The good ending

Answer (score 0):

One has to "walk right past" the compiler warnings about that code.

Below is the same code with coercive casting to silence some of the warnings. An additional calculation and print statement should make obvious how the compiler deals differently with the values of pointers (memory addresses) and the values of integers.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int a = 1;
    printf("value of a = %d\n", a);
    printf("address of a = %u\n", &a); // incorrect format spec for printing address

    int *p;
    printf("value of p = %d\n", p); // uninitialised and undefined behaviour

    p = (int*)2; // coercive casting integer to pointer-to-integer
    printf("value of p = %d\n", p); // incorrect format spec for a memory address

    a = (int)(a + p); // coercive casting address to integer
    printf("value of addition =%d\n", a);

    // ADDED these statements
    a = 1; // restore value of a
    a = a + (int)p; // coercive casting address to integer
    printf("value of addition =%d\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

```
value of a = 1
address of a = 1703728
value of p = 1
value of p = 2
value of addition =6
value of addition =3    <== was this the expected result?
```

C will try to do its best with explicit program statements.
"Garbage in, garbage out."
Write correct code, not 'cute' code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response Awayy. Helpful.
I got the output I needed. But the thing I need to know is, in what logic
the line a = a+p; gave 6 as result in my code.

As u said I'm assigning 2 as address to p(which is p = 0x2).
So, when the addition happens a = 1 and p = 0x2 which has a random value that we don't know that is because I'm not assigning a particular address to the pointer variable p. It results 6 I'm I right.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).